# What's the code for > pointing downwards?

Tags: html, css, unicode

In HTML, greater than is rendered by code: `&gt;`, what is the code for the same symbol but pointing upwards and downwards?

Comment: Usually people use `v` and `^`, no special code needed

Comment: You can point downward with `v` (the letter) and upward with `^`. That's not some HTML special character and no need to escape

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML character codes for this ▲ or this ▼](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6041209/html-character-codes-for-this-or-this)

Comment: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2303/index.htm

Comment: I know that using ```v``` and ```^``` could possibly do, but still they are different from ```&gt;``` in terms of the shape

Comment: I don't understand why my question is marked as duplicated, I'm asking for ```>```, the existing question answers for ```▶```, it does not answer my question.

Comment: Have your pick: Latin capital letter v: V; Canadian syllabics pe: ᐯ; N-ary logical or: ⋁; Mathematical sans-serif italic capital v: ; Tifinagh letter yadh: ⴸ; Latin small letter v: v; Mathematical sans-serif capital v: ; Cyrillic capital letter izhitsa: Ѵ; Mathematical sans-serif italic small v: ; Roman numeral five: Ⅴ; Modifier letter capital v: ⱽ; Latin subscript small letter v: ᵥ; Greek vocal notation symbol-14: ; Countersink: ⌵; Mathematical italic capital v: ; Mathematical sans-serif small v: ; Cyrillic small letter izhitsa: ѵ; Mathematical monospace capital v: ;…

Comment: … Small roman numeral five: ⅴ; Modifier letter small v: ᵛ; Cherokee letter do: Ꮩ; Latin letter small capital v: ᴠ; Cyrillic capital letter u: У; Mathematical monospace small v: ; Mathematical sans-serif bold italic capital v: ; Mathematical double-struck capital v: ; Syriac letter sogdian zhain: ݍ; and possibly more.

Comment: possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338667/is-there-an-upside-down-caret-character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't one per se.

Greater Than and Less Than are mathematical symbols and there is no mathematical term expressed by either of them rotated.

The letter `v` and caret symbol (`^`) are vaguely similar, but in many fonts are significant differences.

You could use `>` and then rotate it with CSS … but the semantics would be weird and it would be very unfriendly to screen reader users (as would using `>` as an arrow in the first place).

```css
span {
    display: inline-block;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<span> > </span>
```

It would be better to use a real arrow instead as Unicode includes multiple sets of arrows pointing in 4 directions which match each other in style.

```html
←↑→↓
```

You could also use images (this is a good use of SVGs).

Comment: @Cid — They are shaped differently to `>` (and also have awful and inappropriate semantics)

Comment: @Quentin Do you mean there is no code-generated-symbol which is identical to ```&gt;``` but rotating 90 degrees?

Comment: @thinkvantagedu — Not in the general case. (It's possible some fonts end up making characters like that by coincidence).

Comment: English Character ```V``` is very different from ```>``` when rendered, they can not be used simultaneously.

Comment: @one-hand-octopus depends on the font. You can even make a custom font with any symbols.